# Is this the right way to reconfigure my constructor to use async and await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've read a few articles and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. I'm trying to keep the UI of my MAUI app updating while loading some data.

I'd like to accomplish this:

```
async public DataService()
{
    //initialize stuff here
    await this.GetPayees();
    await this.GetCategories();
    return;
}
```

I've read that you can't have an async constructor, so I've had to redo how I initialize my class.

```
public DataService()
{
    //Take this out here
    //this.GetPayees();
    //this.GetCategories();
    return;
}

async public static Task<DataService> BuildDataServiceAsync()
{
    //await them here
    var dataService = new DataService();
    await dataService.GetPayees();
    await dataService.GetCategories();
    return dataService;
}
```

This has had a cascading effect throughout my code. I have to change return types to Task, and make additional methods async

```
async public Task<List<Payee>> GetPayees()
{
    //Load arbitrary data, 
    if(Payees.Count != 0) return Payees;
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 0, Name = "Food Lion", DefaultCategoryId = 0, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 1, Name = "Work Incorporated", DefaultCategoryId = 1, DefaultIsCredit = true });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 2, Name = "Hardees", DefaultCategoryId = 3, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 3, Name = "Wal-Mart", DefaultCategoryId = 5, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 4, Name = "Aldis", DefaultCategoryId = 0, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 5, Name = "McDonalds", DefaultCategoryId = 3, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 6, Name = "Harris Teeter", DefaultCategoryId = 0, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 7, Name = "Shoe Show", DefaultCategoryId = 2, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 8, Name = "Capital One", DefaultCategoryId = 4, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 9, Name = "Dicks Sporting Goods", DefaultCategoryId = 6, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    Payees.Add(new Payee { Id = 10, Name = "Amazon", DefaultCategoryId = 7, DefaultIsCredit = false });
    return Payees;
}

async public Task<List<Category>> GetCategories()
{
    if(Categories.Count != 0) return Categories;
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 0, Name = "Groceries" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Paycheck" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Shoes" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 3, Name = "Fast Food" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 4, Name = "Credit Card" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 5, Name = "Supplies" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 6, Name = "Recreation" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 7, Name = "Grocery" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 8, Name = "Gross" });
    Categories.Add(new Category { Id = 9, Name = "Grass" });
    return Categories;
}
```

I get the complier warning about not having await in those last two methods. Would I really await all the Add()s?

I just got dependency injection working the way I want to, but this all cascades back to my viewmodel, which has my dependencies injected:

```
public PayeesViewModel(DataService dataService, NavigationService navigationService, ValidationService validationService)
{
    this.dataService = dataService;
    this.navigationService = navigationService;
    this.validationService = validationService;
    Payees = await dataService.GetPayees();
    Categories = await dataService.GetCategories();

    for(int x = 0; x < Payees.Count; x++)
    {
        PayeeDisplay.Add(new PayeeDisplay
        {
            Id = Payees[x].Id,
            Name = Payees[x].Name,
            DefaultCategory = Categories.Find(c => c.Id.Equals(Payees[x].DefaultCategoryId)).Name,
            DefaultCategoryId = Payees[x].DefaultCategoryId,
            DefaultIsCredit = Payees[x].DefaultIsCredit
        });
    }
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Trying to adopt async/await is literally destroying my project.

Comment: Why did you change `GetPayees` and `GetCategories` to return task? They don't contain any async code? Or are these mockups for [so] and these methods do actually call a database asynchronously or something?

Comment: construtors can't be async, factory methods can... But you shouldn't attempt to do CPU or I/O heavy work in any constructor. You should be calling some async method in your view action, not your model construtor.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I was under the impression that if you want to use `await` on a method, that method also needs to be `async`, and in turn return a Task. For right now in the development of my app, I'm just creating lists and using placeholder data until I start implementing SQLite. I wanted to flesh out the UI and business logic before anything else. :)

Comment: `async` allows you to use `await` in a method. You can create a method that returns a `Task` without `async`. If you have nothing to await then you probably don't want to create a method that is `async` / returns `Task` unless you're conforming to an interface or an abstract method. Awaiting a method that returns Task doesnt necessarily make it async either. If a method doesn't actually do something async then it will probably run synchronously anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `async` keyword only enables the use of `await`. If you don't need to use `await`, then you don't need `async`.

`List.Add()` is not an async method, so you wouldn't use `await`. So just remove the `async` keyword; you don't need it.

Asynchronous programming is helpful when the CPU has to wait for an external resource, for example: network requests, requests to file storage, etc. - anything that is not inside the CPU or RAM. Adding an object to a collection is purely an in-memory operation, and so it's not a good fit for asynchronous programming.

I think you would benefit from reading over Microsoft's documentation on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). It's quite well-written.

---

*Update:*

Since you said that the calls to `Add()` are just placeholders for SQL access, then yes, you would want to use `async` for the SQL calls, and the way you did it is correct: create an `public static async` method that will create an instance of the class for you. This is called a "factory method." You can even go a step further and [make the constructor private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors) so you can enforce the use of the factory method:

```
private DataService() {}

public static async Task<DataService> BuildDataServiceAsync()
{
    var dataService = new DataService();
    await dataService.GetPayees();
    await dataService.GetCategories();
    return dataService;
}
```

Having a private constructor is important if `GetPayees()` and `GetCategories()` must be called for the object to be in a usable state.

Comment: Adding objects to a collection is just a placeholder for SQL access in the current state of my app. It pauses my UI for a second or two and I don't want that to happen. I've read that particular Microsoft doc, and even followed along with the breakfast example. I'll read the documentation again.

Comment: If it's a placeholder for SQL access, then yes, that's somewhere you would want to use `async`/`await`. I've updated my answer.